# Proving that Number of Steps to Return to the Origin is an Even Number

Tags: induction

I was watching the following video on Random Walks: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iH2kATv49rc

Here, the following point is discussed:

- Suppose you have an infinite square grid.
- In each "step", you can move one "step" in the Up, Down, Left or Right Direction
- Suppose you are at the origin at step = 0
- Given this information, is only possible to return to the origin in an even number of steps

**My Question:** While I think this is obvious, I was interested in knowing how statements like this can be mathematically proven.

I think this can be proven using mathematical induction ($n$ is the number of steps).

- When $n$ = 0, you are at the origin
- Assume that in $2n$ steps you can return to the origin: And $2n$ is an even number
- Now consider $2n+2$ steps :  $2n+2$ is also an even number
- Since you can only return in an even number of steps and $2n+2$ is an even number - the proof is concluded.

Is this sufficient to conclude the proof?

Thanks!

**References:**

- [How many paths are there such that we return to the origin in 2m steps?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2787809/how-many-paths-are-there-such-that-we-return-to-the-origin-in-2m-steps)

Comment: No, it is not a valid proof. It nowhere treats the case of treks of odd length.  For instance, a purported round trip of length 9 steps is not invalidated anywhere in your logic.

Comment: @Paul Tanenbaum: thank you so much for your reply! Can you please suggest a different way to prove this if you have time? thank you so much!